# need help Web extracting <ul> and <li> using scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Currently learning scrapy and with only a small knowledge of extracting a  and  tags but in need of help when it comes to extracting ul and li for example:

```
response.css('a.example')

response.css('div.example')
```

but what is the command for 'ul' and 'li"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing here is an understanding of CSS selectors. For example,

- `a.example` would select `<a>` elements with `class` set to `exmaple`
- `div.example` would select `<div>` elements with `class` set to `exmaple`
- `.example` would select every element where `class` is `example`

Once you learn this, you would know that selecting `ul` and `li` doesn't need a separate command. you just need to use the correct selector.
Here is an example:

```
<ul>
<li> one</li>
<li> two</li>
</ul
```

Now if you want to select the text inside the first li element, you would use

```
response.css('li::text).get()
```

If you want to extract both the element's text, you would use

```
response.css('li::text).getall()
```

I would suggest to go through sites like [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) and understand CSS selectors

Comment: ahh thank you very much will do check out the link too :)

Comment: If my answer has helped you, mark it Accepted